# Issue while installing Mailbox Role during migration from Exchange 2003 to 2010

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, exchange-2010, exchange-2003, migration

I am in the process of a migrating our domain exchange server from Exchange 2003 to Exchange 2010. I thought I had prepared my server with all the necessary roles, permissions and updates but I am getting a failure when I go to install Exchange 2010 on my new 2008 R2 machine.

Here are my steps thus far;

1) Installed fresh copy of Server 2008 R2 SP1 (set up static ip, downloaded and installed updates)
2) Added ADDS and DNS roles
3) Ran DCPROMO and promoted the new Exchange server to a DC.
4) Added Web (IIS) role and management tools
5) Downloaded and installed Office filter pack 2.0

At this point I went ahead and started installing Exchange which processed perfectly until it got to the Mailbox Role during the installation, at which point I received the following error:

```
Mailbox Role
Failed

Error:
The following error was generated when "$error.Clear();
          if ($RoleIsDatacenter -ne $true)
          {
            if (test-ExchangeServersWriteAccess -DomainController $RoleDomainController -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
            {
              # upgrade the discovery mailboxes to R5 version, this will fix the RecipientDisplayType property of the discovery mailbox which was wrong in R4.
              get-mailbox -RecipientTypeDetails DiscoveryMailbox -DomainController $RoleDomainController | where {$_.IsValid -eq $false} | set-mailbox -DomainController $RoleDomainController
              $name = [Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.EnableMailbox]::DiscoveryMailboxUniqueName;
              $dispname = [Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.EnableMailbox]::DiscoveryMailboxDisplayName;
              $mbxs = @( get-mailbox -Filter {name -eq $name} -IgnoreDefaultScope -resultSize 1 );
              if ( $mbxs.length -eq 0)
              {
                $dbs = @(get-MailboxDatabase -Server:$RoleFqdnOrName -DomainController $RoleDomainController);
                if($dbs.Length -ne 0)
                {
                  $mbxUser = @(get-user -Filter {name -eq $name} -IgnoreDefaultScope -ResultSize 1);
                  if ($mbxUser.Length -ne 0)
                  {
                    enable-mailbox -Discovery -identity $mbxUser[0] -DisplayName $dispname -database $dbs[0].Identity;
                  }
                }
              }
            }
            else
            {
              write-exchangesetuplog -info "Skipping creating Discovery Search Mailbox because of insufficient permission."
            } 
          }
        " was run: "Database is mandatory on UserMailbox. Property Name: Database".

Database is mandatory on UserMailbox. Property Name: Database
Click here for help... http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms.exch.err.default(EXCHG.141).aspx?v=14.1.218.11&e=ms.exch.err.Ex88D115&l=0&cl=cp

Error:
The following error was generated when "$error.Clear();
          if ($RoleIsDatacenter -ne $true)
          {
            if (test-ExchangeServersWriteAccess -DomainController $RoleDomainController -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
            {
              # upgrade the discovery mailboxes to R5 version, this will fix the RecipientDisplayType property of the discovery mailbox which was wrong in R4.
              get-mailbox -RecipientTypeDetails DiscoveryMailbox -DomainController $RoleDomainController | where {$_.IsValid -eq $false} | set-mailbox -DomainController $RoleDomainController
              $name = [Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.EnableMailbox]::DiscoveryMailboxUniqueName;
              $dispname = [Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.EnableMailbox]::DiscoveryMailboxDisplayName;
              $mbxs = @( get-mailbox -Filter {name -eq $name} -IgnoreDefaultScope -resultSize 1 );
              if ( $mbxs.length -eq 0)
              {
                $dbs = @(get-MailboxDatabase -Server:$RoleFqdnOrName -DomainController $RoleDomainController);
                if($dbs.Length -ne 0)
                {
                  $mbxUser = @(get-user -Filter {name -eq $name} -IgnoreDefaultScope -ResultSize 1);
                  if ($mbxUser.Length -ne 0)
                  {
                    enable-mailbox -Discovery -identity $mbxUser[0] -DisplayName $dispname -database $dbs[0].Identity;
                  }
                }
              }
            }
            else
            {
              write-exchangesetuplog -info "Skipping creating Discovery Search Mailbox because of insufficient permission."
            } 
          }
        " was run: "Database is mandatory on UserMailbox. Property Name: Database".

Database is mandatory on UserMailbox. Property Name: Database
Click here for help... http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms.exch.err.default(EXCHG.141).aspx?v=14.1.218.11&e=ms.exch.err.Ex88D115&l=0&cl=cp

Elapsed Time: 00:03:25
```

I scanned through the error (I admit that my eyes went a little crossed when I started trying to make sense of it.) and the only (maybe) productive info I pulled out of it was a notification of "insufficient permission" but I'm not sure what permissions that pertains to and how to correctly configure them.

Any guidance with this issue is greatly appreciated!

Comment: [The accepted answer in this thread may be what you're looking for](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/10ad4a1e-3108-4016-85cc-8e679e2e8fc9/exchange-2010-sp1-update-issues?forum=exchange2010).  That error is usually the result of not preparing AD before installation, or, failing that, the AD object for the discovery search mailbox being in the wrong place or having the wrong permissions on it.  Let me know.

Comment: Yes I think you're, right. Thank you for the quick catch and the reference to what sounds like the solution. I'll be trying the solution later today or maybe tomorrow and I'll let you know how it works out. Thanks again!